# How can I make home's documents, pictures, videos, downloads to point their matching windows folders in a mounted ntfs partition?

Tags: mount, ntfs, 14.04, symbolic-link

I'd like ~/Downloads, ~/Documents etc. to be mapped (or mounted..? or linked..?) to my matching windows folders (my ntfs partitions are auto-mounted at /mnt).

In other words, what I want is that each time I save a file to ~/Downloads, it will be created at Windows' "My Documents" folder and so forth. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

- Case-1:

You Should Install Synchronizer For Synchronizing Folders Between Two Places.

Conduit-Synchronizer is Best for Ubuntu. Do Auto Synchronize Option.
[image]

- Case-2:

If you Want to Permanently change Default Folders for Downloads, Pictures, etc., You can Use ubuntu-tweak.

[image]

Comment: "ubuntu-tweak"? Are you talking about Unity Tweak Tool? Can you give more information on how do I get to the last screenshot you've just posted? Reminding: 14.04 @Pandya

Comment: Ubuntu-Tweak is Tweak Tool For Ubuntu. (Homepage:-http://ubuntu-tweak.com) (For Adding PPA Goto http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/getdeb_apps?dist=trusty)